# Using cornerstone3D in React with Vite - cannot get image to display

Tags: reactjs, vite, cornerstonejs

I'm having trouble getting the [cornerstone3d](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D) [Render Stack of Images tutorial](https://www.cornerstonejs.org/docs/tutorials/basic-stack) working with React and Vite.

For the registerWebImageLoader function I'm using [the example found here](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D/blob/main/packages/core/examples/webLoader/registerWebImageLoader.ts) which is [referred to in the cornerstone (legacy) Image Loader](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWebImageLoader#cornerstone-web-image-loader).

It appears a viewport-element and cornerstone-canvas are being added to the DOM, but the canvas is all black and no image is shown.

The only error I'm seeing in the console is:

> init.ts:123 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tier')
> at init (init.ts:123:24)
> at async App.tsx:29:36

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import {
  Enums,
  RenderingEngine,
  imageLoader,
  init,
} from "@cornerstonejs/core";

import registerWebImageLoader from "./utils/registerWebImageLoader";

const renderingEngineId = "myRenderingEngine";
const viewportId = "myViewport";
const imageIds = [
  "web:https://cs3d-jpg-example.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a_vm1460.png",
];

const { ViewportType } = Enums;

registerWebImageLoader(imageLoader);

export default function App() {
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = React.useState(false);

  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const initializationResult = await init();
      setIsInitialized(initializationResult);
    })();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isInitialized) return;

    const wrapper = wrapperRef?.current;

    if (!wrapper) return;

    const renderingEngine = new RenderingEngine(renderingEngineId);

    renderingEngine.enableElement({
      viewportId,
      element: wrapper,
      type: ViewportType.STACK,
    });

    const viewport = renderingEngine.getViewport(viewportId);

    viewport.setStack(imageIds, 0);

    viewport.render();
  }, [isInitialized]);

  return (
    <div
      id={viewportId}
      ref={wrapperRef}
      style={{
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px",
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I also tried getting [the example found here to work](https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D/blob/main/packages/core/examples/webLoader/index.ts), but did not have any luck with that, either. Same black box and no images displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Got this sorted out - turns out you need to do quite a bit more initialization than just the initialization for @cornerstonejs/core.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import {
  Enums,
  RenderingEngine,
  imageLoader,
  metaData,
  volumeLoader,
} from "@cornerstonejs/core";

import { hardcodedMetaDataProvider } from "./utils/hardcodedMetaDataProvider";
import { initDemo } from "./utils/initDemo";
import { registerWebImageLoader } from "./utils/registerWebImageLoader";

const imageIds = ["web:https://picsum.photos/500"];
const renderingEngineId = "myRenderingEngine";
const viewportId = "myViewport";
const volumeId = "myVolume";

registerWebImageLoader(imageLoader);

metaData.addProvider(
  (type, imageId) => hardcodedMetaDataProvider(type, imageId, imageIds),
  10000
);

/** 
 * @description Basic working example of cornerstone3D with React using a stripped down version of the webLoader example linked below. Their initDemo function seemed to be the key to getting this working.
 * @link https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D/blob/main/packages/core/examples/webLoader/index.ts
 * @link https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone3D/blob/main/utils/demo/helpers/initDemo.js
 */
async function run(container: HTMLDivElement) {
  try {
    const { initializationResult } = await initDemo();

    if (!initializationResult) throw new Error("Initialization failed");

    const renderingEngine = new RenderingEngine(renderingEngineId);

    const volume = await volumeLoader.createAndCacheVolume(volumeId, { imageIds });

    renderingEngine.setViewports([
      {
        element: container,
        type: Enums.ViewportType.STACK,
        viewportId: viewportId,
      },
    ]);

    const viewport = renderingEngine.getStackViewports()[0];

    volume.load();

    await viewport.setStack(imageIds);

    await viewport.setImageIdIndex(0);

    renderingEngine.render();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const container = containerRef.current;

    if (!container) return;

    run(container);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      id={viewportId}
      ref={containerRef}
      style={{
        height: "500px",
        width: "500px",
      }}
    />
  );
}
```